# Check whether a timestamp is older or newer than another

Tags: php, timestamp

I have 2 Timestamps like 
`2015-06-26 17:43:18` and `2015-06-26 17:22:08`.

How can I check whether the first timestamp is earlier than the second?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`DateTime()` objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which are comparable:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2015-06-26 17:43:18');
$date2 = new DateTime('2015-06-26 17:22:08');
if ($date1 < $date2) {
    // $date1 is earlier than $date2
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/388187)